# jQuery each and do I need to create a closure here?

Tags: jquery, closures, underscore.js

I have the following (shortened the array) that uses jQuery and Underscore:

```
var all_methods = ['locations', 'items', 'by-cocktails'];
var to_methods = [];
$.each(all_methods, (function (key, val) {
    if ($('.lm-search-options[data-action=' + val + ']').hasClass('del')) {
        console.log('to remove: ' + val); // <- only the last piece is moved out despite multiple pieces being here
        to_methods = _.without(all_methods, val);
    }
}));
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that only the last of the selected dom elements is removed (yes, I know this isn't going to win any software design awards). For example, if 'locations' and 'items' are to be removed, only 'items' is removed. Is the behavior I'm seeing due to the fact that there needs to be a new closure here?

Comment: I think using [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) is a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $opts = $('.lm-search-options');
var to_methods = _.filter(all_methods, function(val){
    return !$opts.filter('[data-action=' + val + ']').hasClass('del')
})
```

Comment: oh, at least I could kinda understand the original answer :-); so filtering via a chain of elements.... thx, let me test this out

Comment: @timpone this seems to be a better answer

Comment: ok, is there any way you can tell me what I am doing wrong in my original - do I need a closure for it to work. Will use your answer as it's shorter but just doing a lot more JS the past week and some of (ok, all) the closure syntax / semantics are throwing for a loop.

Comment: @timpone your problem was you were always overriding the value of `to_methods` by removing the last item from `all_methods`

Comment: @timpone like in the first iteration `location` is removed then `to_methods` becomes `['items', 'by-cocktails']`, but if the next iteration `items` are removed then instead of removing it from the modified array (from which location was removed) you are removing it from the source array which contains all elements, now `to_methods` becomes `['locations', 'by-cocktails']` instead of `['by-cocktails']`

Comment: thx @Arun - I misunderstood how underscore is actually working and thought it was acting on a reference to the original array rather than returning a copy. thx again for your help.